# Centering textview with right aligned button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an arbitrary length textview+icon (icon+text) that needs centering on the screen.  On the same row, there is a button aligned to the right side of the screen. (X)

|     icon+text     | X |

Using a LinearLayout I can center it with the view, but the button on the right shifts it left.

With a relative layout, I can achieve what I want but if the text is too long the button overlaps the text.

What's the right way to do this? I haven't used constraintLayout before, would that solve it?

Comment: Does the `Button` on the right have a fixed width or is it `wrap_content`?

Comment: it's a fixed width imagebutton.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a constraint layout,

**Example:**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".YourActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
        android:text="My Long Text That must not overlap the button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/my_btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/my_btn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/my_btn"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="My Nice Button "
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/my_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Example Output:**

[image: example]

Comment: thanks for this, but the text isn't centered to the screen.  it's centered within the left column.

Comment: @Deefer try setting the text gravity to be right aligned with this layout.  What you're trying to achieve is not how xml constraints are setup. At best you can set barriers which will produce similar result, shifting the textview to the left. Note that textViews are rectangular and what you're trying to achieve breaks that which is not possible (if I'm understanding correctly)

Answer (score 1):

You can set it like this,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:text="Click" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question. the text is not centered in the linearlayout

Comment: Okay, You just need to set the property of TextView to android:gravity="center", Please check the Edited code snippet

Comment: this is what I had initially, but in my original statement:
"Using a LinearLayout I can center it with the view, but the button on the right shifts it left."

it's centered in the view, but not overall within the parent.

Answer (score 1):

just use a Relative Layout.
Center your Textview
and put toRightOf=txtViewsName on the button.

//UPDATED Forcing Widths in DP to ensure text is always centered and never overlaps button.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:maxWidth="230dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="My text to show test abcdefghyijkldkf here" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You will need to adjust the button width and textview maxwidth to match your design, and confirm on preview all resolutions, but dp should cover you pretty well in this case.

NOTE*
This simply answers your issue, but does not do any funny behavior, i.e. if text grows too much ignore center command and start moving to the left, this does not do that. If that is your desire, please update your question.

//Centering Text in left view and using weight to ensure text area takes proper percentage of the space (based on your comments, not the layout you are looking for, but I'll leave it in case it helps someone else).

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="My text to show here" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the issue with this is that if the text is short, the button is not aligned to the right side.  it's stuck to the right side of the text

Comment: oh man, I misunderstood, then lol. Here I'll update my answer.

Comment: There you go @Deefer, i updated above to match your request. Let me know if that is not what you are looking for but weight should do the trick for ya. Just play with the weight until you like the split. If you aren't familiar, weight is an arbitrary value that you make up and then assign chunks of the pie to the children. Sometimes easiest to just have weight sum of 100 then think of it like 100% and hand out chunks from there. Or use 10, or 1, or whatever makes sense to you for your designer. It's all the same just gets defined and distributed.

Comment: the issue with this as I originally indicated is that the text is centered within the textview and not the LinearLayout (which is what I really want).
so the text needs to be centered on the screen, as if the button isn't there. but then the button needs to be there too.  (the button is a simple small X image)

Comment: ok, that's what I originally thought, but your | . text . | x | you had the text centered in the left view. So your goal is to have the text centered in the parent view, button to the far right owns it's space no matter what. Then the text does what? Grows evenly left and right until it hits the button then grows left? or truncates? I tried to match your picture, so now that I know what you need, I'll help you again. You may have to get a little clever or hacky to do it, but it can be done.

Comment: ok @Deefer please see the update, this should solve your issue. If your desire is to "only remain centered' until you run out of space, then that is a different layout we would have to do either a little custom or hacking, but I'm happy to try and figure it out for you if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for this.  using maxWidth is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

for best practice i think `ConstraintLayout` is the best solution for designing and yes of course it helps you for what are you looking for. 
for more info check this [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) and this 
[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout).

Answer (score 0):

Since your `ImageButton` on right has a fixed width (let's say `40dp` for the purpose of this example) you can achieve the desired result by adding a margin of the same width at the end of your `TextView` to ensure that they're not overlapping. To keep the `TextView` centered on the screen you have to add the same margin at the start as well:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

If you want to center the text within the `TextView` use         `android:gravity="center"`:

[image]

If the `ImageButton's` width was `wrap_content` then this approach wouldn't work, because there is no way to constraint the end of the `TextView` both to the end of the parent (so it's centered on the screen) and to the start of the `ImageButton` (so they don't overlap if the text gets long) at the same time.

Comment: use of margin and maxWidth should give me resonable results.  Thanks again.  Constraint layouts still mystify me somewhat :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up using RelativeLayout per Sam's suggestion with maxWidth and margin set on the TextView.